# Are there any Large playable races with a LA of +0/+1 and if so where are they?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, dnd-3e, races, creature-size

I know of the half-minotaur that's in a dragon mag somewhere but other than that I have no idea.  I've been consulting lists of +0 and +1 LA playable races and templates but they don't seem to mention whether a creature is Large sized or not, and I've been looking up each creature individually.  I'm also concerned that these lists aren't always comprehensive.  HD doesn't really matter as most creatures with HD can be scaled back with work, but if they have 0/1 HD that's even better.

To clarify, "playable races" in this instance means any race or creature that can be played by a PC, regardless of whether there is a character creation notation in their entry.

Comment: I've altered the wording of the title slightly to possibly be more accurate. ("Large creatures" -> "Large playable races") Please check if the change is OK.

Comment: @Miniman Powerful Build does not count in this context.  Looking for specifically Large sized.

Comment: @doppelgreener I suppose it's ok since that's kind of the effect I meant, however in some cases people interpret "playable races" differently.

Comment: [Strongly related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45786/4563)

Answer (score 10):

Off the top of my head, your options for +0/+1 LA large-sized races are:

- Half-Minotaur (Dragon Magazine #313, +1 LA)
- Half-Ogre (also Dragon Magazine #313, +1 LA)
- Anthropomorphic Baleen Whale (Savage Species, +0 LA, 3 RHD)
- Incarnate Construct Maug (Savage Species, Fiend Folio, +1 LA, 2 RHD)
- Goliath Barbarian (Races of Stone, only while raging, powerful build while not raging +1 LA)
- Half-Giant (Expanded Psionics Handbook, Powerful Build, not actually large, +1 LA)
- Incarnate Construct Dustform Creature (Savage Species, Sandstorm, +0 LA, any humanoid-shaped creature with no LA otherwise can be put through it,
  will keep their racial hit dice)

Honorable Mentions:

- Lycanthrope 1 (Savage Progression) for a Large-sized animal will get
  you Alternate Form into that animal, but it does not give you natural
  attacks, stats, or other bonuses. However, since the Savage
  Progressions generally put large size as an ability gained through
  having several hit dice, the DM is well within his rights to not let
  you take a Large form until you've put some more levels into it. If
  you can find a Large-sized animal with one hit die, you can take that
  one hit die, though.
- Hidden Talent (*Expansion*) (Expanded Psionics Handbook, feat) gives you the ability to use the power of the same
  name a few times per day. Normally this would be fairly useless, but
  if you Use Magic Device (emulating race and emulating manifester
  level) some Power Link Shards (Magic of Eberron, psionic item), you
  can use them to augment it to a 10 minute duration.
- Athas Human
  (Dragon 319, +1 LA) with Inborn Power (*Expansion*) has a manifester
  level, so it can pull the same trick, but it will last 10 minutes per
  character level. They also have the capacity to augment it normally
  once you hit level 3.
- *Permanency*'d *Enlarge Person* on any Humanoid creature with CL 20 costs 3,700gp going by the standard rates.

Comment: Probably worth noting that goliaths still have Powerful Build while not raging, since you mention half-giants.

Comment: Good point! Added.

Comment: Doesn't half-minotaur have a LA of at least +1?

Comment: It does. I'd written it like that because it was directed at the OP, and didn't think it completely through. Edited to show the LA and source.

Comment: Mok'Nathal in WoW d20 have Powerful Build. After taking their Racial Class they become large.

Comment: Given that the question is tagged for D&D 3e and 3.5, that's not particularly relevant. If one is bringing in third-party material, it seems simpler to just make up a Large-sized race on the spot. I think I'd likely just rule that the PC could have a permanent (Ex) enlarge person for LA +0, since it's got a lot of downsides to go with the benefits.

Comment: Am I missing something? The Dustform Creature template does not change the size, how it can help?