# Is this a doable character build in this particular instance?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-3.5e, character-creation, weapons, races

I've been debating this for a couple weeks now and I was wondering if this is a doable build, and if a DM would even be likely to allow this considering it is almost entirely home brewed.

I am want to try a Chaotic Neutral Fullangr with a few levels in Barbarian and a few levels in Smithing.

https://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Fullangr_(3.5e_Race)#Fullangr

For reference this is the page my brother in law found for me.

I am hoping that with this and a two weapon style and exotic weapon proficiency.  I'll be able to dual wield siege axes. Can't figure out how to get a link for that one.

1 the axes are two handed not giant sized. (1 Figured that the character having the str and racial trait of counting as one size larger would make it a one handed for him.
    Since I also like playing where the DM has everyone choose one melee and one ranged weapon I was wanting to wrap chains around the forearms to use as improvised gauntlets and whips if necessary for this character.

With the main special things about them being that they have a silencing rune on them from the father, and other runes to allow each one to have an end that is free hanging or can reattach to the rest on command. that way they wind back onto the arms and stay there i thought acting as either gauntlets or improvised bucklers.

Or can unwind to be used like whips or grapple hooks when needed.  Semi inspired by both Ghost Rider and God of War.  This way he has worn them for so long that they no longer effect him as merely cumbersome and only have the natural weight problem but no extra penalties that many like to throw out as a heavy cumbersome weapon causes for nearly any roll at all.  Also since when retracted they would attach to themselves they still allow for full mobility and use of hands for grasping and holding other objects and weapons.   2 The chains are not connected to the axes they are actually fused to his arms and when needing them out of the way they wrap around the arms and secure themselves. Or when needed they unravel and can be used for binding or whips or something similar. I had the thought of doing it like God of Wars chains on the weapons. Most of the time they are there but dont hinder the grip and only attach to the weapons when needed for a last resort hail mary pass ( because of the massive possible penalties for such a manouvre. 
Was thinking maybe he learned to fight like a barbarian from the mother while she was able and smithing from the father for the same reason.  Figured if he'd been trained since an early age to wear the chains and how to use them and the same for the siege axes that would help backstory wise on why he can walk around with such heavy cumbersome equipment without many of the drawbacks.

I mean I have been repeatedly told that backstories are what allow many characters to do things they shouldnt be allowed to do if you follow the wording of RAW to a precise detail, right?

#### The next thing I wanted to do is a mount or companion.

In a dark cave, what he found was a dark warlock or sorcerer or whatevers abandoned experiment lab where through use of both chemicals and dark magics had been creating their own chimeras or hybrids.  Almost everything in the lab had been butchered or already was.  The state of the place and stench makes it hard to determine.  So he decides to be merciful and move through the horrors of this place one cell at a time and check everything while quickly and painlessly as he can putting down anything that seems to be suffering which is pretty much everything.  When suddenly he hears a small whimpering that seems even more out of place.   He looked around until he found the source.  Surrounded by the corpses of several of the butchers are a large black male Dire Wolf already dead and an equally large silver coloref female Warg.  Between them are several different colored pups who are obviously their litter.

Some looked healthy some not so much is a single pup still alive nuzzling the mother and whimpering. It is coal black like the father but has the spotted pattern like the mother in a definite silver color making it resemble what he names it on the spot.  "Night Sky" he kept it, nursed it to full heath, and raised it until one day it decided he was its new packmate and it would stay and keep its pack safe.

#### Can I make this work in D&D 5e, or do I need to stick with D&D 3.5e ?

With the information provided in this situation is this a workable character build for 5e?  Or should I stick with 3.5 which is really all I have any experience with at this point. I ask because my little sister and brother in law are trying to wrangle me into a 5e game but I have absolutely no experience with this system and what is or isnt allowed anymore.

Comment: Generally, Stack Exchange sites need to have a single, answerable question in each question.  This has too much background (irrelevant to the core question, I think) and too many unclear questions.  You should edit the question to focus on a single question that can be answered, then ask additional questions if needed.

Comment: I figured the added background is what made the build (maybe) doable with the explanation of such and my explaining my reasons while also specifying why I was hoping it would work in this specific situation instead of trying to turn it into one massive work around for a loophole of the whole game.   Just figured it would help with the core issue of "Is this a doable character?"

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you're asking if this highly specific character concept can be built in D&D 5th edition. That seems answerable, though I fear the question will have accumulated close votes (due perhaps to its inclusion of much backstory that doesn't affect the build iself) before an answer can be completed.

Comment: If you don't mind, I am going to edit this question so that your wall of text in paragraph three does not scare off potential answerers.

Comment: You've got a lot to unpack in here and a much of it is more discussion-friendly than Q&A. You may want to check out our [chat] once you've earned 20 rep or try discussing this on a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)

Comment: So in all honesty if I wanted to play this character as written then my best bet is to stick to what I know and stay with 3.5?

Comment: @BradleyLindsey Yes.  If you have the time, you will probably enjoy 5e in its own right with your brother and sister, but if you only have one game, and this is the character that tickles your fancy, the two answers below suggest that is your answer.  As a 5e DM myself, I find myself in agreement with both of the answers.  we have some Q&As on this site that spell out how 5e and 3.5 e are not compatible. And they are not.  The key difference is in Bounded Accuracy.

Comment: Pop that term into the search bar if you are interested in seeing how that applies.

Answer (score 10):

## No, not in the slightest

You're trying to make a D&D 5e character, and you want to play:

**A half dwarf / half giant**

This is not something that exists in D&D 5e by default, so you'd have to homebrew it

**who dual-wields giant-sized axes**

also not allowed, you can't dual wield two-handed weapons in 5e

**attached to magic item chains that leave his hands free**

also not allowed, this would be a homebrew magic item and potentially a gamebreaking one, and characters in 5e do not start with magic items.

**and who rides on some special warg**

Maybe if your DM allows you, but also not allowed by default RAW.

Honestly, your character idea reads more like a background for a story you're writing, than something for a D&D character. You also seem to be under the misunderstanding that you can "make things possible if its in your background", but that's not how D&D works. Backgrounds do provide some benefits in D&D 5e, but they're in the form of extra skills. In your case, your character could gain proficiency in Smithing Tools, because they learned how to smith, but this is based on strict rules on what you can and can't gain.

Simply writing down "has a lot of money" in your characters background does not allow you to start with more money, and writing down this block of text in your character sheet will likewise not allow you to break the rules.

As an advice, if you want to get into D&D 5e, try playing something slightly more mundane to learn the rules first, and leave the crazy homebrews until you're more familiar with the system.

Comment: @KRyan It wasn't intended to be judgy, it was intended more as a "it sounds like you're trying to write a story based on D&D, rather than making an actual D&D character". I've rephrased it to something that should better get that across.

Comment: Yup, excellent, thanks.

Comment: 1 the axes are two handed not giant sized.     (1 Figured that the character having the str and racial trait of counting as one size larger would make it a one handed for him.

Comment: 2 The chains are not connected to the axes they are actually fused to his arms and when needing them out of the way they wrap around the arms and secure themselves.  Or when needed they unravel and can be used for binding or whips or something similar.  I had the thought of doing it like God of Wars chains on the weapons. Most of the time they are there but dont hinder the grip and only attach to the weapons when needed for a last resort hail mary pass ( because of the massive possible penalties for such a manouvre

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense. Thanks Korvin.

Answer (score 7):

### Some of this is do-able in 5e, but some is not.

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking if this highly specific character build can be made in D&D 5th edition.

#### Do-able

Some of this is possible, and your DM wil probably grant most requests:

- Backstory details are entirely fine in 5th edition.
- The Fullangr doesn't exist in D&D 5e, but the [goliath](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/goliath) may do much of what you want, having a bonus to Str and Con. You could play a goliath and just call it a fullangr if you want.
- Weapons that never seem to blunt are probably okay, since D&D weapons don't normally blunt anyway by the rules, so this bonus is not huge.
- You can have a whip and describe it like a chain.
- You can [wield an outsized weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/161269/27377) (thanks [enkryptor](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/27377/enkryptor) for noticing this), though you have disadvantage, so it's not good.
- You can play a **warlock** with the **pact blade** option: they gain numerous abilities including to summon a weapon in whatever form they desire.

#### Not do-able

- You can wield outsized weapons in 5th edition, but at Disadvantage, which is a severe penalty. If your character build is based around wielding outsized weapons for increased efficacy, it's not going to work well.
- There's no such thing as a siege axe in D&D 5th edition.
- You normally don't start with magic items at level 1 in 5th edition. That means no silencing rune.
- You can't grapple at a distance with a whip.
- You can't play a race with +2 Str and +4 Con. In my opinion, Eiji-kun's content at dnd-wiki.org is often highly overpowered, and not a good benchmark for what should be possible in D&D, even in 3.5.
- You can have a mount, but exotic mounts are available at DM's discretion and would cost more money than you have at level 1.

> I mean I have been repeatedly told that backstories are what allow many characters to do things they shouldnt be allowed to do if you follow the wording of RAW to a precise detail right?

- You can't use backstory to justify rule-breaking builds in D&D, at least not in the context of following rules-as-written. If you follow the rules-as-written, they let you do things regardless of backstory. If your DM allows backstory to grant any other ability, that's not rules-as-written.

Anything other than this is up to your DM to allow.

Comment: Does the powerful build racial trait not allowed the two handed weapon one handed use in 5e

Comment: @BradleyLindsey That's really a different question, but no, it does not. It just allows you to carry more weight.

Comment: Yeah I finally found a link to read up on it. But thanks Theik.